# Trouble in executing cake shell in cron

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.x and want to execute a shell in cron.

My purpose of running a shell as background process is to generate a XML file which will contain a large number of data.

I have set the PATH variable to  path/to/app/Console in .bashrc file. I have also created the cakeshell file in /app/Console/cakeshell and made it executable as described in cakephp 2.x documentation. Also i have created my shell inside /app/Console/Command/myjobShell.php.

Here is the code of the cakeshell:

```
#!/bin/bash
TERM=dumb
export TERM
cmd="cake"
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    if [ "$1" = "-cli" ] || [ "$1" = "-console" ]; then
        PATH=$PATH:$2
        shift
    else
        cmd="${cmd} $1"
    fi
    shift
done
$cmd
```

**Note:** I have changed the `cmd='cake'` to its full path `cmd='/path/to/app/Console/cake'`

The cron syntax i have used given below:

```
* * * * * /path/to/cakeshell myjob -cli /usr/bin -console /path/to/app/Console
```

I have checked in server that cron demon is working properly. But it seems that cakeshell is not working.

Also if anybody has any reference of running a /controller/action directly through cron and not using shell could also be a solution. But i don't have any idea if it is feasible or not.

Comment: Did you try with full paths for all files and commands?

Comment: Does it work if you run the command manually? Is it possible it's caused by the 'dumb' shell? Permissions may also be a problem when running something via a cron job, as the cron job may be running as a different user